# Arrange columns on top of each other with tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data frame that essentially consists of several (repeating) blocks (measuring stations) and thus contains several identical variables per line:

```
# ┌───┬───┬───┐ ┌───┬───┬───┐   ┌───┬───┬───┐
# │ A │ B │ C │ │ D │ E │ F │ … │ X │ Y │ Z │
# └───┴───┴───┘ └───┴───┴───┘   └───┴───┴───┘
```

Is there a simple/elegant way to bring these columns on top of each other with tidyverse? By the way, the columns of each block consist of the same data type (i.e. `A = D = … = X`).

```
# ┌───┬───┬───┐
# │ A │ B │ C │
# ├───┼───┼───┤
# │ D │ E │ F │
# ├───┼───┼───┤
# │ … │ … │ … │
# ├───┼───┼───┤
# │ X │ Y │ Z │
# └───┴───┴───┘
```

My attempt to do this with [`pivot_longer()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) has been unsuccessful so far, unfortunately, because it takes the other columns into account and I get some kind of cross set as a result, which makes my initial situation much worse.

Below is an exemplary data frame for the problem above:

```r
data <- data.frame(
  # First block
  a = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  b = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  c = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  # Second block
  d = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  e = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
  f = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6),
  # Third block
  x = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7),
  y = c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8),
  z = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 9)
)
```

The desired result should look like the following data frame:

```r
data_final <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7),
  b = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8),
  c = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the function `splitIndices` which comes bundled with `R` in the `parallel` package (`parallel` is now in base `R`, so you don't need to install it). This allows you to create a list of indices. Then you select, rename, and bind:

```r
# indices
idx <- parallel::splitIndices(ncol(data), 3)

# split and rename
data <- lapply(idx, function(i) setNames(data[, i], c("a", "b", "c")))

# bind
do.call("rbind", data)
```

Answer (score 0):

A loop approach:

```
#Code
index <- c(1,4,7)
index2 <- index+2
df <- data.frame()
#Bind
for(i in 1:length(index))
{
  piece <- data[,index[i]:index2[i]]
  names(piece) <- c('a','b','c')
  df <- rbind(df,piece)
}
```

Output:

```
df
   a b c
1  1 2 3
2  1 2 3
3  1 2 3
4  1 2 3
5  1 2 3
6  4 5 6
7  4 5 6
8  4 5 6
9  4 5 6
10 4 5 6
11 7 8 9
12 7 8 9
13 7 8 9
14 7 8 9
15 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is `tidyverse` approach using `pivot_longer`. Note however, that I renamed the columns slightly to make this approach work:

```
df <- data <- data.frame(
  # First block
  a_1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  b_1 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  c_1 = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  # Second block
  a_2 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  b_2 = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
  c_2 = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6),
  # Third block
  a_3 = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7),
  b_3 = c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8),
  c_3 = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 9)
)

pivot_longer(df, everything(), names_to = c(".value", "dummy"), 
             names_pattern = "(.)_(.)") %>%
  arrange(dummy)
```